# Создание каталога в web-приложении

Tags: java, файлы, intellij-idea

Здравствуйте. Пишу небольшое веб-приложение на Java. Являюсь новичком в этой области и возникшая ошибка не дает покоя уже несколько дней и стопорит всю работу.
Суть в следующем: 
Есть страница, сервлет и экшн. В экшене необходимо создать директорию, в простейшем случае:

```
File file = new File("web/temp");
file.mkdir();
```

На такие действия получаю "отказано в доступе" (Пользуюсь Tomcat 8.5.2.4, Запускаю из под среды IntelliJ Idea)
НО! Если в этом же проекте создаю отдельно класс main с точкой входа и в таком случае каталог успешно создается. С чем это связано, ума не приложу. Но из вышесказанного могу только сделать вывод, что это проблема с доступом к записи именно у Tomcat. Буду рад мыслям по этому поводу. Спасибо

Comment: Я сейчас переосмыслил свой вопрос. В общем получается, я фактически пытаюсь создать директорию по относительному пути в то время, как war уже задеплоил на сервер. Естественно, сделать у меня этого не получается, но использовать абсолютный путь тоже не хочется

Comment: Да, действительно. Все каталоги, которые я пытался создать, нашел их там. В таком случае получается, что все загруженные изображения будут храниться в папке томката. Нормальная ли это практика? Или же необходимо каким-то образом переназначить этот каталог? Спасибо

Comment: Да, но суть в том, что каталог внутри проектной папки, значит загруженные файлы, например изображения не будут обновляться динамически. Нужно редеплоить вар, ну как вариант думаю написать сервлет, который будет вытаскивать стрим по абсолютному пути и сразу же выводить картинку.